# How to align the title of html legend tag in chrome

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, jsf, primefaces

i want to know how to align the title of a legend, at the left position in google chrome, because in Firefox its showing in the left position but in Chrome not.

i´m using css and html5.

Comment: Show the code that you have so far.

Comment: fieldset {
 border: 1px solid orange;
 height: auto;
 display: block;
 padding: 8px;
}

legend {
 font: bold 10px verdana;
 color: black;
 display: block;
 -webkit-padding-start: 2px;
 -webkit-padding-end: 2px;
 border: none;
}

Comment: To align legend in chrome, you do that with text-align.So if you set  legend to: text-align:left; it will sit on left.If not, it inhertits text-align.

Comment: Check and play in Chrome with legend & text-align here : http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/qkmfe

Comment: I tested in chrome, and div tag its the problem....

So i want to put this code

 <div align="center">
  <fieldset>
   <legend>Teste</legend>
   Teste: <input type="text"/><br />
   Teste: <input type="text"/><br />
   Teste: <input type="text"/>
  </fieldset>
 </div>

To align the title in the left and the text edits in the midle